# How do you force a listPreference to reset it's value?

Tags: android, listpreference

I have a ListPreference and it has a default value and it works great.  I also have a preference that resets all the shared preferences which works great.  The problem is that if you go back into the ListPreference it is still showing the old value.  If you exit the preferences completely and go back in, it shows correctly.

So the question is how can I force the ListPreference to use the correct value?  Every other preference seems to be working just fine.

I did find a work around but I am not happy with it as it seems dirty to me.  When the user clicks on the reset, after values have been reset, I set the value myself to the value it is already set too.

```
( (ListPreference) findPreference( myListKey ) ).setValue( String.valueOf( DEFAULT_VALUE ) );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Azizi Musa is onto something, but null will throw an exception.

This worked however:

```
ListPreference yeeha = (ListPreference) findPreference ("yeeha");

yeeha.setValue("");
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its late, but maybe someone else stumbling upon this might find it useful.

```
Preference reset = (Preference) findPreference("reset");
reset.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    preference.getEditor().clear().commit();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Restored to default settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: @user1780619 does not work for me at all - it does not clear the list selection

Answer (score 1):

```
ListPreference pref = (ListPreference) findPreference ("yeeha");

pref.setValue(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should override onSetInitialValue method from ListPreference.
like this.

public class CustomListPreference extends ListPreference{

protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {

//when it alreay init or not your option value
if(restoreValue){

}else{
//set it to defautlValue

}

}

}

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem to set my list of categories in the *ListPreference*. The problem is that you can not change the visible options in the dialog with the list by the *setEntries* method (setting entries in on the click listener is too late).

The solution for me was adding the *DrawerListener* which tells my PreferenceFragment when it should invalidate.

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

final MainOptionsFragment fragment = (MainOptionsFragment) getFragmentManager().
            findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);

mDrawerOptions = new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        fragment.onOpened();
    }
};

mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerOptions);
```

Another solution is overwriting the *onPrepareDialogBuilder* method, which would set the entries before the dialog is prepared.

```
class CustomListPreference extends ListPreference {
    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) {
        // TODO setEntries
        super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);
    }
}
```